# TensorFlow Inference

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow

I've been digging around on this for a while. I have found a ton of articles; but none really show just tensorflow inference as a plain inference.  Its always "use the serving engine" or using a graph that is pre-coded/defined.

Here is the problem: I have a device which occasionally checks for updated models. It then needs to load that model and run input predictions through the model.

In keras this was simple: build a model; train the model and the call model.predict(). In scikit-learn same thing.

I am able to grab a new model and load it; I can print out all of the weights; but how in the world do I run inference against it?

Code to load model and print weights:

```
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(MODEL_PATH + '.meta', clear_devices=True)
        new_saver.restore(sess, MODEL_PATH)
        for var in tf.trainable_variables():
            print(sess.run(var))
```

I printed out all of my collections and I have:
['queue_runners', 'variables', 'losses', 'summaries', 'train_op', 'cond_context', 'trainable_variables']

I tried using `sess.run(train_op)`; however that just started kicking up a full training session; which is not what I want to do. I just want to run inference against a different set of inputs that I provide which are not TF Records.

Just a little more detail:

The device can use C++ or Python; as long as I can produce a .exe.  I can set up a feed dict if I want to feed the system.  I trained with `TFRecords`; but in production I'm not going to use `TFRecords`; its a real/near real time system.

Thanks for any input.  I am posting sample code to this repo: https://github.com/drcrook1/CIFAR10/TensorFlow which does all the training and sample inference.

Any hints are greatly appreciated!

------------EDITS-----------------
I rebuilt the model to be as below:

```
def inference(images):
    '''
    Portion of the compute graph that takes an input and converts it into a Y output
    '''
    with tf.variable_scope('Conv1') as scope:
        C_1_1 = ld.cnn_layer(images, (5, 5, 3, 32), (1, 1, 1, 1), scope, name_postfix='1')
        C_1_2 = ld.cnn_layer(C_1_1, (5, 5, 32, 32), (1, 1, 1, 1), scope, name_postfix='2')
        P_1 = ld.pool_layer(C_1_2, (1, 2, 2, 1), (1, 2, 2, 1), scope)
    with tf.variable_scope('Dense1') as scope:
        P_1 = tf.reshape(C_1_2, (CONSTANTS.BATCH_SIZE, -1))
        dim = P_1.get_shape()[1].value
        D_1 = ld.mlp_layer(P_1, dim, NUM_DENSE_NEURONS, scope, act_func=tf.nn.relu)
    with tf.variable_scope('Dense2') as scope:
        D_2 = ld.mlp_layer(D_1, NUM_DENSE_NEURONS, CONSTANTS.NUM_CLASSES, scope)
    H = tf.nn.softmax(D_2, name='prediction')
    return H
```

notice I add the name `'prediction'` to the TF operation so I can retrieve it later.

When training I used the input pipeline for `tfrecords` and input queues.

```
GRAPH = tf.Graph()
with GRAPH.as_default():
    examples, labels = Inputs.read_inputs(CONSTANTS.RecordPaths,
                                          batch_size=CONSTANTS.BATCH_SIZE,
                                          img_shape=CONSTANTS.IMAGE_SHAPE,
                                          num_threads=CONSTANTS.INPUT_PIPELINE_THREADS)
    examples = tf.reshape(examples, [CONSTANTS.BATCH_SIZE, CONSTANTS.IMAGE_SHAPE[0],
                                     CONSTANTS.IMAGE_SHAPE[1], CONSTANTS.IMAGE_SHAPE[2]])
    logits = Vgg3CIFAR10.inference(examples)
    loss = Vgg3CIFAR10.loss(logits, labels)
    OPTIMIZER = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(CONSTANTS.LEARNING_RATE)
```

I am attempting to use `feed_dict` on the loaded operation in the graph; however now it is just simply hanging....

```
MODEL_PATH = 'models/' + CONSTANTS.MODEL_NAME + '.model'

images = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(1, 32, 32, 3))

def run_inference():
    '''Runs inference against a loaded model'''
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        #sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(MODEL_PATH + '.meta', clear_devices=True)
        new_saver.restore(sess, MODEL_PATH)
        pred = tf.get_default_graph().get_operation_by_name('prediction')
        rand = np.random.rand(1, 32, 32, 3)
        print(rand)
        print(pred)
        print(sess.run(pred, feed_dict={images: rand}))
        print('done')

run_inference()
```

I believe this is not working because the original network was trained using TFRecords.  In the sample CIFAR data set the data is small; our real data set is huge and it is my understanding TFRecords the the default best practice for training a network.  The `feed_dict` makes great perfect sense from a productionizing perspective; we can spin up some threads and populate that thing from our input systems.

So I guess I have a network that is trained, I can get the predict operation; but how do I tell it to stop using the input queues and start using the `feed_dict`?  Remember that from the production perspective I do not have access to whatever the scientists did to make it.  They do their thing; and we stick it in production using whatever agreed upon standard.

-------INPUT OPS--------

tf.Operation 'input/input_producer/Const' type=Const, tf.Operation 'input/input_producer/Size' type=Const, tf.Operation 'input/input_producer/Greater/y' type=Const, tf.Operation 'input/input_producer/Greater' type=Greater, tf.Operation 'input/input_producer/Assert/Const' type=Const, tf.Operation 'input/input_producer/Assert/Assert/data_0' type=Const, tf.Operation 'input/input_producer/Assert/Assert' type=Assert, tf.Operation 'input/input_producer/Identity' type=Identity, tf.Operation 'input/input_producer/RandomShuffle' type=RandomShuffle, tf.Operation 'input/input_producer' type=FIFOQueueV2, tf.Operation 'input/input_producer/input_producer_EnqueueMany' type=QueueEnqueueManyV2, tf.Operation 'input/input_producer/input_producer_Close' type=QueueCloseV2, tf.Operation 'input/input_producer/input_producer_Close_1' type=QueueCloseV2, tf.Operation 'input/input_producer/input_producer_Size' type=QueueSizeV2, tf.Operation 'input/input_producer/Cast' type=Cast, tf.Operation 'input/input_producer/mul/y' type=Const, tf.Operation 'input/input_producer/mul' type=Mul, tf.Operation 'input/input_producer/fraction_of_32_full/tags' type=Const, tf.Operation 'input/input_producer/fraction_of_32_full' type=ScalarSummary, tf.Operation 'input/TFRecordReaderV2' type=TFRecordReaderV2, tf.Operation 'input/ReaderReadV2' type=ReaderReadV2,

------END INPUT OPS-----

----UPDATE 3----

I believe what I need to do is to kill the input section of the graph trained with TF Records and rewire the input to the first layer to a new input.  Its kinda like performing surgery; but this is the only way I can find to do inference if I trained using TFRecords as crazy as it sounds...

Full Graph:

[image]

Section to kill:

[image]

So I think the question becomes: How does one kill the input section of the graph and replace it with a `feed_dict`?

A follow up to this would be: is this really the right way to do it?  This seems bonkers.

----END UPDATE 3----

---link to checkpoint files---

https://drcdata.blob.core.windows.net/checkpoints/CIFAR_10_VGG3_50neuron_1pool_1e-3lr_adam.model.zip?st=2017-05-01T21%3A56%3A00Z&se=2020-05-02T21%3A56%3A00Z&sp=rl&sv=2015-12-11&sr=b&sig=oBCGxlOusB4NOEKnSnD%2FTlRYa5NKNIwAX1IyuZXAr9o%3D

--end link to checkpoint files---

-----UPDATE 4 -----

I gave in and just gave a shot at the 'normal' way of performing inference assuming I could have the scientists simply just pickle their models and we could grab the model pickle; unpack it and then run inference on it.  So to test I tried the normal way assuming we already unpacked it...It doesn't work worth a beans either...

```
import tensorflow as tf
import CONSTANTS
import Vgg3CIFAR10
import numpy as np
from scipy import misc
import time

MODEL_PATH = 'models/' + CONSTANTS.MODEL_NAME + '.model'
imgs_bsdir = 'C:/data/cifar_10/train/'

images = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(1, 32, 32, 3))

logits = Vgg3CIFAR10.inference(images)

def run_inference():
'''Runs inference against a loaded model'''
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(MODEL_PATH + '.meta')#, import_scope='1', input_map={'input:0': images})
        new_saver.restore(sess, MODEL_PATH)
        pred = tf.get_default_graph().get_operation_by_name('prediction')
        enq = sess.graph.get_operation_by_name(enqueue_op)
        #tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess)
        print(rand)
        print(pred)
        print(enq)
        for i in range(1, 25):
            img = misc.imread(imgs_bsdir + str(i) + '.png').astype(np.float32) / 255.0
            img = img.reshape(1, 32, 32, 3)
            print(sess.run(logits, feed_dict={images : img}))
            time.sleep(3)
        print('done')

run_inference()
```

Tensorflow ends up building a new graph with the inference function from the loaded model; then it appends all the other stuff from the other graph to the end of it.  So then when I populate a `feed_dict` expecting to get inferences back; I just get a bunch of random garbage as if it were the first pass through the network...

Again; this seems nuts; do I really need to write my own framework for serializing and deserializing random networks?  This has had to have been done before...

-----UPDATE 4 -----

Again; thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Alright, this took way too much time to figure out; so here is the answer for the rest of the world.

**Quick Reminder**: I needed to persist a model that can be dynamically loaded and inferred against without knowledge as to the under pinnings or insides of how it works.

**Step 1**: Create a model as a Class and ideally use an interface definition

```
class Vgg3Model:

    NUM_DENSE_NEURONS = 50
    DENSE_RESHAPE = 32 * (CONSTANTS.IMAGE_SHAPE[0] // 2) * (CONSTANTS.IMAGE_SHAPE[1] // 2)

    def inference(self, images):
        '''
        Portion of the compute graph that takes an input and converts it into a Y output
        '''
        with tf.variable_scope('Conv1') as scope:
            C_1_1 = ld.cnn_layer(images, (5, 5, 3, 32), (1, 1, 1, 1), scope, name_postfix='1')
            C_1_2 = ld.cnn_layer(C_1_1, (5, 5, 32, 32), (1, 1, 1, 1), scope, name_postfix='2')
            P_1 = ld.pool_layer(C_1_2, (1, 2, 2, 1), (1, 2, 2, 1), scope)
        with tf.variable_scope('Dense1') as scope:
            P_1 = tf.reshape(P_1, (-1, self.DENSE_RESHAPE))
            dim = P_1.get_shape()[1].value
            D_1 = ld.mlp_layer(P_1, dim, self.NUM_DENSE_NEURONS, scope, act_func=tf.nn.relu)
        with tf.variable_scope('Dense2') as scope:
            D_2 = ld.mlp_layer(D_1, self.NUM_DENSE_NEURONS, CONSTANTS.NUM_CLASSES, scope)
        H = tf.nn.softmax(D_2, name='prediction')
        return H

    def loss(self, logits, labels):
        '''
        Adds Loss to all variables
        '''
        cross_entr = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, labels=labels)
        cross_entr = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entr)
        tf.summary.scalar('cost', cross_entr)
        tf.add_to_collection('losses', cross_entr)
        return tf.add_n(tf.get_collection('losses'), name='total_loss')
```

**Step 2**: Train your network with whatever inputs you want; in my case I used Queue Runners and TF Records.  Note that this step is done by a different team which iterates, builds, designs and optimizes models.  This can also change over time.  The output they produce must be able to be pulled from a remote location so we can dynamically load the updated models on devices (reflashing hardware is a pain especially if it is geographically distributed).  In this instance; the team drops the 3 files associated with a graph saver; but also a pickle of the model used for that training session

```
model = vgg3.Vgg3Model()

def create_sess_ops():
    '''
    Creates and returns operations needed for running
    a tensorflow training session
    '''
    GRAPH = tf.Graph()
    with GRAPH.as_default():
        examples, labels = Inputs.read_inputs(CONSTANTS.RecordPaths,
                                          batch_size=CONSTANTS.BATCH_SIZE,
                                          img_shape=CONSTANTS.IMAGE_SHAPE,
                                          num_threads=CONSTANTS.INPUT_PIPELINE_THREADS)
        examples = tf.reshape(examples, [-1, CONSTANTS.IMAGE_SHAPE[0],
                                     CONSTANTS.IMAGE_SHAPE[1], CONSTANTS.IMAGE_SHAPE[2]], name='infer/input')
        logits = model.inference(examples)
        loss = model.loss(logits, labels)
        OPTIMIZER = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(CONSTANTS.LEARNING_RATE)
        gradients = OPTIMIZER.compute_gradients(loss)
        apply_gradient_op = OPTIMIZER.apply_gradients(gradients)
        gradients_summary(gradients)
        summaries_op = tf.summary.merge_all()
        return [apply_gradient_op, summaries_op, loss, logits], GRAPH

def main():
    '''
    Run and Train CIFAR 10
    '''
    print('starting...')
    ops, GRAPH = create_sess_ops()
    total_duration = 0.0
    with tf.Session(graph=GRAPH) as SESSION:
        COORDINATOR = tf.train.Coordinator()
        THREADS = tf.train.start_queue_runners(SESSION, COORDINATOR)
        SESSION.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        SUMMARY_WRITER = tf.summary.FileWriter('Tensorboard/' + CONSTANTS.MODEL_NAME, graph=GRAPH)
        GRAPH_SAVER = tf.train.Saver()

        for EPOCH in range(CONSTANTS.EPOCHS):
            duration = 0
            error = 0.0
            start_time = time.time()
            for batch in range(CONSTANTS.MINI_BATCHES):
                _, summaries, cost_val, prediction = SESSION.run(ops)
                error += cost_val
            duration += time.time() - start_time
            total_duration += duration
            SUMMARY_WRITER.add_summary(summaries, EPOCH)
            print('Epoch %d: loss = %.2f (%.3f sec)' % (EPOCH, error, duration))
            if EPOCH == CONSTANTS.EPOCHS - 1 or error < 0.005:
                print(
                'Done training for %d epochs. (%.3f sec)' % (EPOCH, total_duration)
            )
                break
        GRAPH_SAVER.save(SESSION, 'models/' + CONSTANTS.MODEL_NAME + '.model')
        with open('models/' + CONSTANTS.MODEL_NAME + '.pkl', 'wb') as output:
            pickle.dump(model, output)
        COORDINATOR.request_stop()
        COORDINATOR.join(THREADS)
```

**Step 3**:  Run some Inference.  Load your pickled model; create a new graph by piping in the new placeholder to the logits; and then call session restore.  DO NOT RESTORE THE WHOLE GRAPH; JUST THE VARIABLES.

```
MODEL_PATH = 'models/' + CONSTANTS.MODEL_NAME + '.model'
imgs_bsdir = 'C:/data/cifar_10/train/'

images = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(1, 32, 32, 3))
with open('models/vgg3.pkl', 'rb') as model_in:
model = pickle.load(model_in)
logits = model.inference(images)

def run_inference():
    '''Runs inference against a loaded model'''
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        new_saver = tf.train.Saver()
        new_saver.restore(sess, MODEL_PATH)
        print("Starting...")
        for i in range(20, 30):
            print(str(i) + '.png')
            img = misc.imread(imgs_bsdir + str(i) + '.png').astype(np.float32) / 255.0
            img = img.reshape(1, 32, 32, 3)
            pred = sess.run(logits, feed_dict={images : img})
            max_node = np.argmax(pred)
            print('predicted label: ' + str(max_node))
        print('done')

run_inference()
```

There definitely ways to improve on this using interfaces and maybe packaging up everything better; but this is working and sets the stage for how we will be moving forward.

**FINAL NOTE**  When we finally pushed this to production, we ended up having to ship the stupid `mymodel_model.py file down with everything to build up the graph.  So we now enforce a naming convention for all models and there is also a coding standard for production model runs so we can do this properly.

Good Luck!

Comment: For those interested, this was too much song and dance.  We use CNTK now instead... It was easier to standardize everything for all teams and get something into production consistently.

Answer (score 6):

While it's not as cut and dry as model.predict(), it's still really trivial.

In your model you should have a tensor that computes the final output you're interested in, let's name that tensor `output`. You may currently just have a loss function. If so create another tensor (variable in the model) that actually computes the output you want.

For example, if your loss function is:

```
tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(last_layer_activation, labels)
```

And you expect your outputs to be in the range [0,1] per class, create another variable:

```
output = tf.sigmoid(last_layer_activation)
```

Now, when you call `sess.run(...)` just request the `output` tensor. Don't request the optimization OP you normally would to train it. When you request this variable tensorflow will do the minimum work necessary to produce the value (e.g. it won't bother with backprop, loss functions, and all that because a simple feed forward pass is all that's necessary to compute `output`.

So if you're creating a service to return inferences of the model you'll want to keep the model loaded in memory/gpu, and repeat:

```
sess.run(output, feed_dict={X: input_data})
```

You won't need to feed it the labels because tensorflow won't bother to compute ops that aren't needed to produce the output you are requesting. You don't have to change your model or anything.

While this approach might not be as obvious as `model.predict(...)` I'd argue that it's vastly more flexible. If you start playing with more complex models you'll probably learn to love this approach. `model.predict()` is like "thinking inside the box."

Comment: My only follow up question is; how do I extract 'output' from the graph?  I am perfectly happy always naming the final tensor 'output' as the "interface" definition.  The issue is the device only has access to the model/checkpoint files; it does not have the graph construction code.

Comment: I added a name to the softmax layer in hopes I can retreive that tensor and give a shot:     H = tf.nn.softmax(D_2, name='prediction') previously that tensor had not been explicitly named.

Comment: Giving this a shot; and it appears to simply lock up:     with tf.Session() as sess:
        new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(MODEL_PATH + '.meta', clear_devices=True)
        new_saver.restore(sess, MODEL_PATH)
        pred = tf.get_default_graph().get_operation_by_name('prediction')
        print(sess.run(pred, feed_dict={images: np.random.rand(1, 32, 32, 3)}))

Comment: I think I'm running into a problem where it expects the input queues to be running and populating data into the queue.  I did not use feed_dict to train; I used tfRecords...

Comment: `result_output = sess.run(output)` will compute and return the tensor `output`. If you're reading from queues and loading those queues from tfRecords you'll need to start a thread that runs the `enqueue` op in a loop, the QueueRunner class is designed to do this. There's nothing special about the name `output`, call it whatever you like. You will need to pass that tensor to `sess.run(...)`, so either look it up by name (there are many S.O. articles on looking up tensors by name), or save it somewhere when you create your graph. I create my graph as an object and make tensors properties.

Comment: Added a section with all of the input ops that got generated by tensorflow via the TFRecord process...I found an op that is 'enqueuemany' 'input/input_producer/input_producer_EnqueueMany' type=QueueEnqueueManyV2 so I can run that; but how do I feed it the random stuff; like simply a np.random.rand(32, 32, 3) or something?

Comment: You have 2 ways of feeding your model, you either feed it from tensorflow readers via a tensorflow queue (use Queuerunner here to read and enqueue data), or you feed it in via `feed_dict` in `sess.run(...)`. Which you use depends on how you set up your graph, where your data is coming from, etc. You need to write code to do either, there's no tensorflow magic happening.

Comment: I resolved it in a way that is acceptable for our use case; see the answer I ended up posting.