# TensorFlow Inference Graph - Loading and Restoring Variables impact

Tags: python, tensorflow

This is closely related to a lot of questions, including one of my own here: [TensorFlow Inference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43708616/tensorflow-inference)

Every sample in TensorFlow for inference appears to follow this form:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import CONSTANTS
import Vgg3CIFAR10
import numpy as np

MODEL_PATH = 'models/' + CONSTANTS.MODEL_NAME + '.model'
rand = np.random.rand(1, 32, 32, 3).astype(np.float32)

images = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(1, 32, 32, 3))

logits = Vgg3CIFAR10.inference(images)

def run_inference():
    '''Runs inference against a loaded model'''
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(MODEL_PATH + '.meta')
        new_saver.restore(sess, MODEL_PATH)
        print(sess.run(logits, feed_dict={images : rand}))
        print('done')

run_inference()
```

Issues:

1. Restoring the model & graph does just that...except I am creating a parallel graph here where I am *possibly* adding new parts to the graph.  (Except tensorflow graphs are append only; so how does this add to the graph and run just that segment if it is appended; it would want to run the whole thing.
2. What happens to the queue runners that existed in the loaded graph; all those ops are loaded.  By printing out sess.graph.get_operations() you can see all of the old input ops are there.
3. Does logits = Vgg3CIFAR10.inference(images) not append new items to the graph?  If it is because of naming; then does the placeholder input replace the queue runner stuff?

Possible answer for a few items:  Because I defined the logits op first; this means that the rest of the graph got appended after that; and via some tensorflow magic sauce the variables from the original graph got restored into the logits portion of the graph?

So I tested this out; and it doesn't even work properly...

It first creates a graph with logits, then it appends to that graph the old graph.  So when you call inference; you just get a bunch of garbage back...

[[ 0.09815982  0.09611271  0.10542709  0.10383813  0.0955615   0.10979554
   0.12138291  0.09316944  0.08336139  0.09319157]]

[[ 0.10305423  0.092167    0.10572157  0.10368075  0.1043573   0.10057402
   0.12435613  0.08916584  0.07929172  0.09763144]]

[[ 0.1068181   0.09361464  0.10377798  0.10060066  0.10110897  0.09462726
   0.11688241  0.09941135  0.0869903   0.09616835]]

Here I am expecting node 8 followed by nodes 2 and 2 to be the ones surfaced...obviously its just a bunch of nothing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a ton of review this is what happens...

1. If you add anything to the graph before restoring the graph; the restored graph is appended to the already created graph.
2. Restoring variables looks for variable names in your graph at the time of restoring variables with the same name as the variables that are stored in the meta files.  If you created a graph with the same variable names, and then restored a graph that also had the same variable names, the test I ran showed the appended stored graph receiving the restoration of the variables and not the initial graph.

So in summary; be careful about what you are doing with your graphs and be very aware of how things get appended/restored.  If you were looking at this in hopes to find inference; then look at this S.O. where the answer involves creating a new graph and restoring variables to that new graph which is in fact a subgraph of the original.

[TensorFlow Inference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43708616/tensorflow-inference/43745667#43745667)