# How to make a network that relies on tf.train.shuffle_batch ready for production

Tags: tensorflow

I've created a `tfrecords` file, which I read via `tf.TFRecordReader`, which has been great for training the network. However, I'm not sure how to dynamically reduce the batch size for production, nor how to feed and override some variable when loading the graph with `tf.train.import_meta_graph`

```
reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
data = tf.train.shuffle_batch(...)
# batch_size 100

IS_TRAINING = tf.placeholder(tf.bool, shape=(), name="is_training")
# tried constant, variable and placeholder with no luck

custom_data = tf.Variable(...)

_data = tf.cond(
    IS_TRAINING,
    lambda: data,
    lambda: custom_data,
    name="condition"
)

coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord, sess=sess)

# network graph

coord.request_stop()
coord.join(threads)

sess.close()
```

I've tried to import the trained graph with `tf.train.import_meta_graph` and using `feed_dict`, tried to override `IS_TRAINING` so the graph uses data that I also feed via `feed_dict`. But nothing has worked so far.

e.g.

```
sess.run([variable], feed_dict={IS_TRAINING:False, custom_data:data})
```

Comment: importing meta graph just gives you the graph definitions of your model (similar effect to parsing and importing a PB file), as well as other things like you saver. I believe the meta_graph import will be rather distinct from your tfrecord pipeline. You can consider using a Dataset class to read your TFRecord files instead, as they will read your data in parallel and shuffle them by default, which gives you a cleaner code. You can consider constructing a model that simply takes in `True` or `False` to change the model to be an evaluation or training one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're loading your data manually instead of from a TF records file you'll want to eliminate the use of `QueueRunner` to load samples (this is only used if you are loading samples using a tensorflow record reader), and instead load the data in `sess.run([ops], feed_dict={data:my_custom_data})`

Change your model to not use shuffle batch anymore, this should not affect your ability to load the checkpoint:

```
data = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(input_shape), name="data")
```

It would be easier just to change the model rather than use the conditional assignment as you've shown. But if you want to use the conditional statement, then `custom_data` should be a placeholder, not a variable.

If you want your code to work in both cases I would use a python if statement at the point where you define the graph, not at graph runtime.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! For training, I've used a `tfRecord` file. But indeed, I won't need to use it for production. Not sure how that would work with `tf.train.import_meta_graph` though?

Comment: Good question, that might be an issue. Instead of importing the meta graph, just rerun your code that builds the graph programmatically, then the restore should work on either graph because only OPS, not variables, were changed.

Comment: your comment above had the right idea. More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43708616/tensorflow-inference)